# How I am supposed to get the real version of Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I set `X-UA-Compatible` to edge but in user agent string it tells me that it is IE7. Is there any clear way to collect statistics of IE versions?

Comment: Please share your markup and/or a brief demonstration of the issue. If you're setting the mode to "edge," but still getting IE 7's user-agent string, it's possible that your user is viewing the page from IE 7, or that the application of *x-ua-compat* is invalid.

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting the user-agent string *after* the document mode has been set, through *navigator.userAgent* for instance.